# Check if inside facebook canvas php sdk 5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to do so with php sdk 5? 
My page runs inside canvas, and I have this code:

```
$helper = $facebook->getCanvasHelper();
$signedRequest = $helper->getSignedRequest();

if ($signedRequest) 
{
echo 'sidned'.$signedRequest;
die();
}
else
{
echo 'unsigned'.$signedRequest;
var_dump ($_POST);
var_dump ($_GET);
die();
}
```

It always returns unsigned array{0} array{0} i.e. no signed info, no $POST info. I want to detect solidly if I am inside facebook canvas, and I googled a lot and seems like signed_request has to be posted all the time. Am I wrong on this one?

Comment: Most likely you are doing some redirect so your code is not running on the first POST

Comment: Hmm, this code I posted is in the top of index.php page, and it immediately calls die(), also I run it by using direct canvas link apps.facebook..xxxxx; So I assume there could not be any redirections involved. Though, that is something to investigate more troughfully, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Check the Network Console in Chrome to see what happens. And the webserver logs to see what requests are made to it

Comment: Thanks, perfect suggestion! There is indeed odd one post request (301 Moved Permanently) with sidgned_request data, so something is going on... How I have that, so can start investigating more

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but inside facebook canvas settings I had to add 'www' before the url; This made POST request properly. Probably has something to do with reserver redirects configuration, but that is out of my area of expertice to digg into it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Today this is the best way to check this :

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app-id',
  'app_secret' => 'app-secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
]);

$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

// Obtain a signed request entity from a page tab
$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
$signedRequest = $helper->getSignedRequest();
$payload = $signedRequest->getPayload();

if($payload['page']) {
    // I am under a page
} else {
    // I am inside facebook canvas
}
```